# how do you add a property to an existing type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a property to the javascript 'Date' prototype.

in javascript, i'd just do this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, "fullYearUTC", {
    get: function () { return this.getUTCFullYear(); },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

I thought I'd just be able to do the following in typescript:

```
class Date
{
    get fullYearUTC(): number { return this.getUTCFullYear() }
}
```

but I get the error

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Date'.
```

why doesn't this work?

*(please no comments on whether or not you think doing this is a good idea. this question is not about that.)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not create a class named `Date`, you can have your own date object which extends it:

```
class MyDate extends Date {
    get fullYearUTC(): number {
        return this.getUTCFullYear();
    }
}
```

But if you want to modify the existing `Date` you need to keep doing what you did with your javascript code.
As for adding it to the ts type, you need to use it as an interface:

```
interface Date {
    readonly fullYearUTC: number;
}
```

Or you can augment the global namespace:

```
declare global {
    interface Date {
        readonly fullYearUTC: number;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. i'd really like to use typescript to implement the properties, though. seems like a hole in the language, IMO.

Comment: You are using typescript, for example if you have a typo and write `configurabl: true` you'll get a compilation error as the object doesn't match the `PropertyDescriptor` type. And you're using typescript when you add your getter using `interface Date` so that from now on all date instance (as far as typescript cares) have `fullYearUTC`. As for the runtime aspect, you just can't redeclare the `Date` object, not with javascript nor with typescript.

Answer (score 65):

#### Intersection Type

In typescript, If you want to add members, you can use an intersection type:

```
type DateWithNewMember <T> = Partial<T>
   & { newMember: boolean }
```

Then use like this:

```
dates: DateWithNewMember<Date>[];
```

#### Union Type

You could use Union type:

```
class newDateClass {
   readonly fullYearUTC: number;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
date: Date | newDateClass
```

Comment: Worth noting that using `Partial` will render all members of the type being amended (`<T>`) as optional. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype